# Pipe grep response to a second command?

Tags: shell, grep

Here's the command I'm currently running:

```
curl 'http://test.com/?id=12345' | grep -o -P '(?<=content="2;url=).*?(?=")'
```

The response from this command is a URL, like this:

```
$ curl 'http://test.com/?id=12345' | grep -o -P '(?<=content="2;url=).*?(?=")'
http://google.com
```

I want to use whatever that URL is to essentially do this:

```
curl 'http://test.com/?id=12345' | grep -o -P '(?<=content="2;url=).*?(?=")' | curl 'http://google.com'
```

Is there any simple way to do this all in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xargs` with a place holder for the output from `stdin` with the `-I{}` flag as below. The `-r` flag is to ensure the `curl` command is not invoked on a empty output from previous `grep` output.

```
curl 'http://test.com/?id=12345' | grep -o -P '(?<=content="2;url=).*?(?=")' | xargs -r -I{} curl {}
```

A small description about the flags, `-I` and `-r` from the `GNU xargs man` page,

```
-I replace-str
       Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
       names read from standard input. 

-r, --no-run-if-empty
        If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run
        the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is
        no input.  This option is a GNU extension
```

(or) if you are looking for a `bash` approach without other tools,

```
curl 'http://test.com/?id=12345' | grep -o -P '(?<=content="2;url=).*?(?=")' | while read line; do [ ! -z "$line" ] && curl "$line"; done
```